# I can't figure out why there are spaces in this returned list

Tags: python

I've included the whole problem statement and the code used. As I tried two alternative formulations of the char_list structure both have been included and commented out; the problem persisted in both cases.

Why doesn't `' '.join()` clean out the spaces?

```
'''Write a password generator in Python. Be creative with how you generate passwords - strong passwords have a mix of lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, and symbols. The passwords should be random, generating a new password every time the user asks for a new password. Include your run-time code in a main method.'''


import random

def password_generator():

  #char_str = '1234567890abcdefgh!@#$%(^)%($('
  #char_str = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '1', '2', '3', '4']
  password = []
  length = int(input("How long should the password be?"))

  while len(password) < length:
    password.append(char_str[random.randint(0, len(char_str) - 1)])

  return(' '.join(password))

print(password_generator())
```

Example output: `% ) 0 4 d c f b % 7`

Comment: `' '.join` joins *with* spaces.  Use `''.join` if you don't want spaces

Answer (score 2):

You are joining each character by a literal space, which is why there are spaces between each character. To solve this you could join on an empty string:

```
"".join(password)
```

Or alternatively you could just build a string instead of a list:

```
password = ""
while len(password) < length:
    password += char_str[random.randint(0, len(char_str) - 1]
```

Answer (score -2):

' '.join(password) does that. Do ''.join(password) instead.